# How to authenticate lots of machine-to-machine clients with AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I'm creating an API for a client for which they're going to provide to their own B2B customers, and I'm really struggling with the authentication mechanisms of AWS. I'm not an expert in the area but I have done some integrations in the enterprise world before. Oauth2 with client id and client secrets seems like a well known standard, but AWS seems to have limited support for it.

From my point of view, my requirements seems pretty normal;

**I would like to provide an API to 100+ B2B customers for them to integrate into their business systems (ERP, CRM etc). Within my Lambda's I need access to the authenticated user to fetch some necesarry custom fields or tags**

At some clients there might be a developer who can make anything work (but expects a standard) and at others there might be a standardized service like power apps, API poller etc where the super user just provides basic api details like endpoint, authorization etc.

What I've tried:

- AWS Cognito seems to be made for this, but client id and client secrets are generated on app client level, not per user. A user pool consists of several users and one (or many) app clients. It seems very strange to have one user per pool with a unique app client just to get Oauth to work
- AWS Cognito seems to be made for app user backends where users authenticate via an URL. I can't have B2B customers with ERP integrations having to call an url to get a token. It must use a /token endpoint, but to use that it seems necessary to use client id and client secret (which I can't get per user)
- I've made it work with IAM auth right now, but the AWSSig4 authentication signing might be a problem for some clients. Also - IAM could also grant access to internal AWS resources. I'd like to separate this with more than just IAM policies
- Basic authentication is not preferred but even that doesn't seem possible with any service
- I see that custom lambda authorizers are possible but is it really necessary to go there to solve this fairly simple requirement? Also, to support oauth here, it seems necessary with a third party IDP.
- Some vendors I've integrated against before provides an endpoint, client id, client secret and "cp-apim-subscription-key", which from a quick google search seems to originate from Azure. Is it realy true that this comes out-of-the-box with Azure and are so far away on AWS?

**What is the recommended approach?**

- Have I overlooked something realy basic here or is it AWS that has chosen a different path than others?
- Should I set refresh token vailidity to 10 years in Cognito and just provide tokens directly to users?
- Should I create a custom Lambda authorizer because that's how everyone's doing it?

*I could provide a bunch of URL's to AWS re:post and SO posts here but as neither have answered this challenge I think it will just add unecessary payload to this post ;)*

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Have you given a thought about using Auth0 with custom Authoriser in place ? We do have similar situation in our application.

Comment: Not much thought, but that's because i was hoping everything could be solved in AWS. Don't really want a second user DB somewhere..